# Remove column from postgresql via rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I use this command to create an avatar column in my postgresql database.

```
rails g migration add_avatar_to_users avatar:string
rake db:migrate
```

I have an `image` column i would like to get rid of in the same database. I don't know the command to do so. I dont need the data and that column anymore.

I tried

```
rails destroy migration add_image_to_users image:string
rake db:migrate
```

But it did not fix the problem =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rails g migration remove_image_from_users`

That will generate a new migration, and then inside the `change` method you can write:

```
remove_column :users, :image
```